# How can I produce messages with Kafka 8.2 API in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, maven, apache-kafka

I'm trying to work with the kafka API in java. I'm using the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm having trouble connecting to a remote kafka server.
I changed the kafka 'server.properties' file port attribute to be port 8080.
I can start both the zookeeper and the kafka server no problem.
I can also use the console producer and consumer applications that came with the kafka download. (Scala 2.10 version)

I'm using the following client code to create a remote KafkaProducer

```
Properties propsProducer = new Properties();

propsProducer.put("bootstrap.servers", "172.xx.xx.xxx:8080");
propsProducer.put("key.serializer", org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.class);
propsProducer.put("value.serializer", org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.class);
propsProducer.put("topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms", "0");

KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]> m_kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]>(propsProducer);
```

Once I've created the producer, I can run the following line and get valid topic info returned, granted strTopic is an existing topic name.

```
List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfo = m_kafkaProducer.partitionsFor(strTopic);
```

When I try to send a message, I do the following:

```
ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> prMessage = new ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]>(strTopic, strMessage.getBytes());

RecordMetadata futureData = m_kafkaProducer.send(prMessage).get();
```

The call to send() blocks indefinitely and when I manually terminate the process, I see that the ERROR Closing socket because of error on kafka server(IOException, Connection Reset by Peer) error.

Also, it's worth nothing that the host.name, advertised.host.name, and advertised.port properties are all still commented out on the 'server.properties' file. Oh, and if I change the line:

```
propsProducer.put("bootstrap.servers", "172.xx.xx.xxx:8080");
```

to

```
propsProducer.put("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:8080");
```

and run it on the same server as where the kafka server is installed, it works but I'm trying to work with it remotely.

Appreciate any help and if I can clarify at all let me know.

Comment: Are you literally using `172.xx.xx.xxx` as a host IP address?

Comment: No, it's a full IP the x's are just masks.

Comment: Kk. Perhaps firewall issue? Can you validate network connectivity on port 8080 using netcat?

Comment: Verified the command 'nc -vz localhost 8080' succeeded on the host server machine. 'netstat -plunt' also posts the port as open and listening on all interfaces.

Comment: .. and on client (producer) `nc -v 172.xx.xx.xxx 8080` connected?

Comment: Client machine is a Windows box. Running 'netstat -an | find "8080"' revealed that a connection was established to the kafka server's port 8080. The Windows machine is acting as the client and hosting a Linux Mint VM that's being used as said server. Did write a quick socket program test (Java Socket and ServerSocket)  this morning and was able to communicate from the VM to Windows on port 8080. And yes, the program has since been shut down.

Comment: @BaronI'm sorry to say I don't know enough about Kafka to be of more help at this point. I peeked at docs and didn't see anything about IP whitelists or such. Maybe I'll think of something tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of digging, I decided to implement the example found here: [Kafka Producer Example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example#). I shortened the code and didn't implement a partitioner class. I updated my pom with the dependency listed and I was still having the same issue. Ultimately, I made some configuration changes and everything worked.

The final piece of the puzzle was defining the Kafka server in /etc/hosts of both the server and the client machines. I added the following to both files.

```
172.xx.xx.xxx     serverHost1
```

Again, the x's are just masks. Then, I set the advertised.host.name in the server.properties file to serverHost1. NOTE: I got that IP after running an ifconfig on the server machine.

I changed the line

```
propsProducer.put("metadata.broker.list", "172.xx.xx.xxx:8080");
```

to

```
propsProducer.put("metadata.broker.list", "serverHost1:8080");
```

The Kafka API didn't like the fact that I was defining an IP as a string. Instead it was looking up the IP from within the etc/hosts file although the documentation says:

"Hostname the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, it uses the value for "host.name" if configured. Otherwise, it will use the value returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()."

Which will just return the IP, in the string form, I was previously using if not defined in etc/hosts of client machine, otherwise it returns the name paired with the IP (serverHost1 in my case). Also, I never did set the value of host.name either.

Comment: Is bootstrap.servers the replacement for metadata.broker.list?

Comment: Yes I believe so. In version 0.8.2.0, the field was "metadata.broker.list" but in newer releases it is "boostrap.servers"

Comment: Yes !! That's tru. with the new ProducerAPI this is the new config.